# Cycles: How can I make a plane both emmissive and transparent?

Tags: light, transparency, shadows

I have the following situation:

I have a scene lighted by a "sun" lamp that gives me good sharp shadows. But I also want to have a large plane with an emissive material placed above the scene to regulate the "general" brightness. My problem is that while this plane does emit light the way I want it to, it also blocks the sun and casts a shadow on my scene. So I want it to both emit light, and by invisible to the rays of the sun. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Cycles Settings*, and disable *Camera* and *Shadow*. And if you don't want to see it in *Solid* mode either, go in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Display* > *Maximum Draw Type* > *Wire*.

Comment: Well that was easier that I thought... thanks! I was building strange node labyrinths and nothing was working.